# Running Angular2 app direcly from VScode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am new to Angular2 and VScode and i am trying to run quickstart application from Angular2 site into VS code. In VScode, there is option called terminal window, which opens command prompt of windows. From this i try to use npm install command but nothing happens.

Is it possible to use npm install and npm start commands to Angular2 application  directly from VScode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Make sure you have latest version of VScode version (1.2.1)

then go to File menu > Preferences > workspace settings.
On right hand side, you will see settings.json. In this file add below line-

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe  /k \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\nodevars.bat\""
```

thats it. now you can run npm install and npm start commands to run your angular2 application.

see if this helps.

Comment: thanks. this was missing in my settings. now i am able to run npm install and npm start in terminal window in vscode.